# Custom Hook for Radio Button with semantic-ui-react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I've created a custom hook to use with a form I've built using semantic-ui-react. The code for the hook looks like this (taken from [here](https://medium.com/@geeky_writer_/using-react-hooks-to-create-awesome-forms-6f846a4ce57) )

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const useForm = callback => {
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({})
  const handleSubmit = event => {
    if (event) {
      event.preventDefault()
    }
  }
  const handleInputChange = event => {
    event.persist()
    setInputs(inputs => ({
      ...inputs,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    }))
  }
  return {
    handleSubmit,
    handleInputChange,
    inputs,
  }
}

export default useForm
```

It works perfectly well with all of my text based inputs at the moment, but I've added some radio buttons like this:

```
<Form.Group inline>
  <label>Number of Hours</label>
  <Form.Radio
    label="<3 Hours"
    name="hours"
    onChange={handleInputChange}
    value="1"
    checked={inputs.hours === 1}
  />
  <Form.Radio
    label="3+ Hours"
    name="hours"
    onChange={handleInputChange}
    value="2"
    checked={inputs.hours === 2}
  />
</Form.Group>
```

But the hook doesn't work properly. I've done some digging and it looks like it's because the onChange (I've tried onClick too) seems to fire on the label in semantic-ui-react, so the event doesn't contain the proper target name or value. The only workaround I can think of is to write some custom handler that creates a fake event that looks for the hidden radio input :before the label, but it seems like there should be a cleaner way.

**Updated Workaround**
I created a custom handler for radios as a temporary workaround and also adjusted the `checked` part to put quotes around the value. It works, but if anyone knows a better way, please share.

This is the custom handler.

```
  const radioHandleInputChange = e => {
    let { value, name } = e.target.previousSibling
    e.target.name = name
    e.target.value = value
    handleInputChange(e)
  }
```